# What is the SPListTemplateType or SPListTemplateId or ListUrl of ACL of an item?

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, elements-xml

What is the SPListTemplateType or SPListTemplateId or ListUrl of the list that appears when clicking on the item permission button on the edit control block or the button on the ribbon of any item (see picture below) ?[image: ACL]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see on that page isn't a list, but a SPGridView with the content populated by the codebehind `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.UserRoles` which you can find in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\XXX\_app_bin\Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll`

In SharePoint 2010 you'll not be able to hookup an eventreceiver to catch any changes made here. But that comes in [SPSecurityEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164667%28v=office.15%29) in SharePoint 2013

Comment: Thank you. I don't know that it isn't a list. So I will use <`custom action`> to create my logic.